# Is there a database of past sunspots?

Tags: sunspots

I would like to plot a [butterfly diagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solar_cycle#Sunspots). I've been looking through the [SOHO archive](https://sohowww.nascom.nasa.gov/data/data.html) for a table that would indicate the date and position of each sunspot, but to no avail. The closest I got was to use [the archived images](https://sohowww.nascom.nasa.gov/data/synoptic/sunspots_earth/) to create the table myself, but that would be extremely fastidious.

Is there a place where I might find this kind of data?

Comment: https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2Fs41116-020-0023-y has maybe some data sources linked. Maybe also this PhD thesis: https://publishup.uni-potsdam.de/opus4-ubp/frontdoor/deliver/index/docId/41360/file/senthamizh_pavai_diss.pdf

Comment: Possibly here: http://www.sidc.be/silso/datafiles

Answer (score 3):

The National Solar Observatory [historical archive](https://www.nso.edu/data/historical-archive/) lists at least one source of sunspot data. Under 'Sacramento Peak Telescope'->'Evans Solar Facility' there is a Dropbox link to [Sunspot numbers data](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/g4s822ex9h0ubsh/AACLlKJ_DkYXq062o-H4tiRIa/sunspots?dl=0&preview=spots.list&subfolder_nav_tracking=1) which seems to have spot numbers against time in ASCII format; this may be a suitable resource to get you going.

Comment: The sunspot number isn't exactly what I'm going for. I would like to have the latitude of the sunspots.

Comment: Makes sense, I will need to do some further digging. I found the quality of data archiving there surprisingly poor, hopefully there is a dataset out there to be found without having to reanalyze all the full-disk solar images.