# Are sunspots named or individually tracked?

Tags: the-sun, data-analysis, naming, sunspots

This is a follow-up question to [How are the solar flares from May 23, 2021 extraordinary?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/43958/37191) which is about news of spaceweather.org. In the present question, I am curious solely about sun-spots and why some of them seem to have names like **AR2824**, and how they are tracked.

So what exactly is that name? Can I find a history about each sun-spot? How are sunspots tracked?

### References

- [Is there a database of past sunspots?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/35337/is-there-a-database-of-past-sunspots)

Comment: Sunspots do have designations, like you said, AR2824. I don't think they have names because they only last so long.

Comment: According to an [answer to my previous question](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/a/43966/37191), the designations actually  refer to *active regions* which are not sunspots. I would like to learn more about those regions, too.